CSS flex layout with columns

I'm relatively new to css, don't know how to make the layout work. There is a column with photo swiper to the left and a column with info to the right. The problem is that on desktop layout (@media (min-width: 992px)) the "buttons" div should be directly under the "info" as part of the right column, but on tablet layout (@media (min-width: 768px)) the buttons need to wrap and become screen-wide, being under both of the columns.
Here's the html template:
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="photo swiper">
    </div>
    <div class="info">
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
    </div>
</div>

The problem is I cannot define the height of .photo or .info classes (only their width), they must remain flexible. And I really don't want to create two separate "buttons" elements for different screen sizes. How can I make this layout?
@media (min-width: 768px)  {
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    gap: 40px;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
.photo{
    width: calc((100% / 1200)* 515);
   }
}


Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

CSS grid might be helpful here.
